# Discord.js - Allow command in specific channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, discord, discord.js

I am owning a Discord.js bot and I can't figure out how to do that :/

I want the users to type the command !help in the #commands channel only.

P.S. I know how to get the channel ID and I have it.

So what should I do in the command event to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `Message.channel.id` property.

Refer to the [discord.js documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=channel) for more

```
client.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.channel.id === 'ChannelID') {
        // Deal with command
    }
});
```

Comment: Worked great! Thank you very much :)

Comment: And when i want to limit it to 2 channels? what do i have to add?

Comment: @NicoHd105 You can simply do an or in the IF statement like "if(msg.channel.id === 'ChannelID-1' || msg.channel.id === 'ChannelID-2') { ... }"

Comment: Thanks, even though i would already know it, but i totally forgot i made this comment 